# Selecting new feature in attribute table of ArcMap without using mouse?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, editing

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

When editing fields of a feature in an attribute table (right-click -> open attribute table with start editing enabled), is there a way to quickly select a new record without using the mouse?

I want the record to be selected so I can see it on the map in order to know what to change the field to.

I am not creating a new record.  I have added a new column to the table and want to add data to the fields in that column.  Before I add the data to the field I want to be sure I am editing the correct record, hence the selection highlighting in both the map and the table.  I can do this by double clicking on the field with the mouse, but it seems like it would be faster to stay on the keyboard.[image: screenshot]

Comment: Would you be able to **edit** your question to clarify whether you are using the Attribute window which is opened from the Editor toolbar, or the Table window that is opened from the layer context menu, please?

Comment: Are you wanting to do some programming to accomplish this? When you create a new record it is automatically selected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here's a handy list of keyboard shortcuts](http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-desktop-tips.pdf).

In an attribute table, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will move to the next row and select it. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> (the equal key) will zoom to that feature in the map.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a bunch, that is a great resource.