# Scrolling through selected records in attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table

I am working with data from GPS tags to determine departure/return times so am I am currently going through the attribute table for each tag and clicking each consecutive record to highlight the point on the map. Is there a way to continuously "scroll" through selected records in the attribute table? I tried with a mouse wheel and arrow keys but they just select one cell of the attribute table and it doesn't highlight the whole record so the point is not highlighted on the map.

Comment: Do you just need to see where each feature is showing up?

Comment: Yes. When the attribute table is open I select the far left box that highlights the whole row teal and also shows where the point is on the map (in teal) and then I select the next row...etc by using my mouse and then record the data from the points I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can select-scroll (scroll-select?) through records of an attribute table with Ctrl + Enter, which will also highlight the feature on the map. If you only want to scroll through a selection of features, you can create a layer from your selection first, and then scroll through that attribute table.

I was looking for this today, so I found your question and [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154286/selecting-new-feature-in-attribute-table-of-arcmap-without-using-mouse), which had the solution.